# What is the best practice to build 4 publich websites on the same database?

Tags: performance, web, service, failover

We have four public websites running on the same database with different schema(Oracle). All of them are 'AAA' application and have "20,0000PV~500,000PV"daily. 90% data in websites are read-only and updated daily(By Batch). Less than 10% data, such as announcement, are updated manually. We are looking for the best practices to solve following concerns.

1. Improve website availability. Though we have a BCP database, it might need 1~2 hours to recover 4 websites in case database server is down.
2. Since most data are read-only, we are considering using in-memory db (hsqldb) or cache component(ehcache) to improve performance. As default, we are using ibatis and hibernate. Ehcache might not only be used on Level-2 cache, but also page cache.
3. We trends to build web services framework(restful) instead of java solution since mobile application might reuse them. Not very sure if it is a good idea to run website on web service on the same web application server. We have active-active HTTP and web servers.
4. On-line shopping is in the future plan.

Comment: Seems more a consulting job statement than a question. I suggest you to go slower, and one for one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add database processes, make it at least 4 for serving each website.
2. Consider memcache
3. The same application server can run multiple applications. Not a problem it there is a good amount of RAM. However, if there is an overwhelm of users, you can always move particular applications to a different server. But, a better idea is to wait and see which service is worth that privilege.
4. Another web-application, too much of security and state management. Better put it in a new server.